# Network fees TrustWallet XTZ stacking

Tags: fees

It would be very much appreciated if you could help me with this
So I’ve been stacking XTZ with Everstake, been receiving first interests payments but every time the fees network represent the majority of the rewards
TrustWallet says that they don’t take any fees but I guess they do
Did it happened to y’all ?

Answer (score 0):

Without an example is not possible to say for 100% certainty (you can find your account and all transactions on a block explorer such as https://tzkt.io), a link or a screenshot of one of the transactions you are discussing would be helpful. However both TrustWallet and Everstake are known to be trustworthy and reliable

All transactions on the blockchain cost a network fee. This is not a charge from TrustWallet or Everstake, its the blockchain itself. Everstake will deduct this fee from your rewards. All bakers also charge a fee (e.g. 5% - 20%) for their services. If you are staking a low amount of Tezos, then yes it is possible a network fee might represent a decent portion of the reward. The expected APR is typically 4% - 6%